# Can't get Terminus to work with PHPStorm

Tags: linux, fonts, debian, phpstorm

The original Terminus just does not appear available in PHPStorm.

I tried installing Terminus.ttf but this one has different sizing and literally broke the look and feel of the whole system (e.g., code in browser is not readable). Besides this Termius in PHPSotrm is not as accurate as the original one.

Is there any way to make the original Terminus work under PHPStorm?

I'm using Debian testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM supports only TTF and OTF fonts (OTF since 1.7), so you need a version of Terminus in the compatible format. Original one will not work.

I've made a [TTF version of Terminus](http://amip.tools-for.net/wiki/jircii/plugins#terminus_ttf_font) many years ago, but it's far from perfect. Probably there is a better one now somewhere.

It may help if you change the font name with a font editor so that it doesn't conflict with the original one (like TerminusTTF). Use the TTF font in the IDE and the original font in the system.

Also [check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233), it has some details in the latest comments how font appearance can be improved in Java applications on Linux.